# knitr: Code Externalization for Python

Tags: python, r, knitr

I use `read_chunk()` to read `R` code from external source. I wonder if there is a similar function to read `Python` code into main document.

Some extract of my `.Rmd` document.

````
R works, of course.

```{r test-r, engine='R'}
library(knitr)
set.seed(123)
rnorm(5)
```

Does **knitr** work with Python? Use the chunk option `engine='python'`:

```{r test-python, engine='python'}
x = 'hello, python world!'
print(x)
print(x.split(' '))
```
````

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman for your comment. `Knitr` can parse Python code properly. Please see my edits and [example for knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/023-engine-python.Rmd). However, I'm interested in Code Externalization for `Python`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course this works with Python:

Create a test.py file with following content:

```
## @knitr abc
print(1)
```

And in your RMD file:

````
```{r}
knitr::read_chunk('test.py')
```

```{r abc, engine='python'}
```
````

Works fine for me.